# Best way to combine bitmap images and audio streams into a video using C#

Tags: c#, video, audio

I have looked at some of the VLC wrappers but haven't tried them yet. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does it have to be real-time, or can you do it in the background?

Comment: Background is fine. I imagine I would launch a worker thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do this in the background and it doesn't need to be realtime, I recommend shelling this out to [FFMPEG](http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/).

FFMPEG can handle tasks like this very easily, and it isn't worth the headache to do this natively in .NET, unless you have to.  (If you were, you'd want to look into DirectX.)

There appears to be a [C# wrapper for .NET](http://www.ffmpeg-csharp.com/), but I have no experience with it.  I should also point out that FFMPEG supports STDIN/OUT.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to give credit for this but I ended up solving it before ever seeing yur answer. I actually decide to just use the FFMPEG executable and my own C# wrapper. I've been impressed by how many great things you can do with that library.